# Как вывести сложные данные в представление ASP.Net MVC5?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть таблица "Скидки", которая в себе содержит внешние ключи для заказчиков и материалов (2-х разных таблиц), а проблема в том, что я не могу вывести данные в представление

Например, страница "Платежи" имеет только ключ на заказчиков, в ней вывести получается как:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

public ActionResult Payments()
{
    var payments = db.Payments.Include(p => p.Customer);
    return View(payments.ToList());
}
```

И в представлении

```
@foreach (var f in Model)
{
    <tr class="content">
        <td><p>@f.Id</p></td>
        <td><p>@f.Date</p></td>
        <td><p>@f.Customer.CustomerName</p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Собственно вопрос - как вывести и заказчиков, и материалы на страницу со скидками?**

**Контроллер**

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

public ActionResult Sales()
{ 
    //Что сюда писать?
    return View();
}
```

**Модель**

```
public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int? MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Material Material { get; set; }

    public float Changes { get; set; }
}
```

**Контекст**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("conn")
    { }

    //Non-inheriting
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }

    //Other
    public DbSet<DeliveryAddress> DeliveryAddresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `var payments = db.Payments.Include(p => p.Customer).Include(p => p.Material);`?

Comment: @tym32167, боже, всё было настолько просто... Спасибо большое...

Answer (score 0):

```
var sales = db.Sales.Include(p => p.Customer).Include(p => p.Material);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]